# How to reset a form on JSP page?

Tags: forms

I want to reset a form which will blank all input field and checkbox.
But here's my code doesn't work.

```
<form id="rwdPromotionDetailsAdd">
     <input type="button" onclick="resetForm()" value="Reset form">
</form>


    <script>
            function resetForm() {
                        document.getElementById("rwdPromotionDetailsAdd").reset();
                    }
<script>
```

How can i reset a form ? Any better suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to insert this within a form

`<input type="reset" value="Reset form">`

Don't even have to attach a listener to it

Comment: You have `type="button"` instead of `reset` like my answer shows

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="rwdPromotionDetailsAdd">
 <input type="button" onclick="resetForm($('#rwdPromotionDetailsAdd'))" value="Reset form">
</form>

<script>
    function resetForm($form) {
        $form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
        $form.find('input:radio, input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
    }
<script>
```